# Facebook API get post content for each post c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I have a list of facebook posts which I need to get contents of.
E.g. :

```
https://www.facebook.com/92979593115/posts/10153657643923116
https://www.facebook.com/92979593115/posts/10153659926668116
https://www.facebook.com/92979593115/posts/10153701531073116
```

etc.

I only need the contents (body) of each post. That's it . I created my app on fb and have id and secret but every time I get Bad Request.

```
string oauthUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}",      "my_client_id", "my_secret");

string accessToken = client.DownloadString(oauthUrl).Split('=')[1];

string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/10153657643923116/posts?access_token={0} ", accessToken);
```

Rohan.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here... This work perfect for me. https://www.hackviking.com/development/facebook-api-login-flow-for-desktop-application/